# Format date in jquery- from Sat Mar 03 2012 14:16:05 GMT+0530 to 03/03/2012

Tags: jquery, datetime, format

How can I format this date?

```
 <li>Sat Mar 03 2012 14:16:05 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)</li>
```

I used new date() function to get date in this li. I want date  like this `03/03/2012`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function dateFormat(){
    var d = new Date();

    date = d.getDate();
    date = date < 10 ? "0"+date : date;

    mon = d.getMonth()+1;
    mon = mon < 10 ? "0"+mon : mon;

    year = d.getFullYear()

    return (date+"/"+mon+"/"+year);
}

dateFormat();
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is tell the date function to format the date to the kind of output you want.

(Assuming you are using date function of JavaScript, which you did mention above.)

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--

    var d = new Date();  
    var curr_date = d.getDate();  
    var curr_month = d.getMonth(); 
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

    document.write(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);

    //-->
</script>
```

OR

http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

OR

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat

```
<script>
    $.format.date("2009-12-18 10:54:50.546", "dd/MM/yyyy");
</script>
```

Comment: :- its giving the output as 3/3/2012  . How can I make it 03/03/2012  ie how do I get zeros before single digits?

Comment: I used ranganadh's answer. You too were a great help. Thanks :)